# Find the agents available capacity in Omni Flow

Tags: email, email2case, omnichannel

Is there a way to find the Agents current capacity before assigning a case to them. I tried using the Check Availability for Routing action in the OmniFlow

[image]

It returns the following values

[image]

But I am not sure here how I can get the agents available capacity, can anyone please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find the availability of a specific agent, then passing in the Agent ID you’ll receive two pieces of information back, one is the number of agents online, which will either be 1 or 0, and the other is the number of items queued up specifically/just for them, which in effect tells you if the agent is at full capacity or not.

I've checked with the Salesforce product team and it’s a feature request to add a ‘current workload’ return variable. Currently, we cannot say what the agents current workload is. Please consider logging an Idea on [idea exchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy)

If it’s a blocker,using customization, you could write your own action to do it:

- Agents current capacity is on the User Service Presence object
- Proportion of that capacity being consumed is the sum of the sizes of all the Agent Work objects with status ‘Active’ assigned to the agent

Comment: Can you please help with https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/397197/route-work-action-on-the-omni-flow-is-throwing-the-error I am just trying the out of box action and it throws error