# Route Work action on the Omni Flow is throwing the error

Tags: visual-workflow, case, omnichannel, recordtriggeredflow

I am trying to explore the Route Work action on the OmniFlow, the omniflow is triggered from an record triggered flow like below

[image]

It checks if the agent available using the Check Availability for Routing action. If it returns '1' the I try to route the case to the agent using Route Work

Everytime I try to trigger this flow it keeps throwing the below error

ROUTE WORK: Route Work to Agent
Inputs:
agentId = {!userId} (005xxxxxxxxxxxx)
botLabel = null
botId = null
skillRequirementsResourceItem = null
isAgentVariable = true
isQueueVariable = true
skillOption = null
queueId = {!Get_QueueId.Id} (00Gdxxxxxxxxx)
recordId = {!recordId} (500xxxxxxxxxx)
routingType = Agent
serviceChannelLabel = Case
serviceChannelDevName = Case
serviceChannelId = 0N9xxxxxxxx

---

Error Occurred: An error occurred. Try again, or contact Salesforce Customer Support and provide this error ID: 1076175125-355133 (-1854618616)

---

---

Salesforce Error ID: 1076175125-355134 (606541954)

Is there something I am missing here, any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Based on salesforce internal logs, I can see the stacktrace `-1854618616` points to `Unexpected error originating from InvocableAction type routeWork.The number of requests and results were not the same. Requests: 1; Results: 2` I will dig further and will let you know as I make progress.

Comment: I've not been able to replicate this GACK in my personal org. Are you running the flow in debug mode? 
I see `ROUTE WORK:agentLabel = chat user
agentId = 0055j000005JdcgAAC
botLabel = null
botId = null
skillRequirementsResourceItem = null
isAgentVariable = false
isQueueVariable = false
skillOption = null
queueId = 00G5j000000uiBgEAI
queueLabel = High-Priority Cases
recordId = {!recordId} (5005j00000KLeK8AAL)
routingType = Agent
serviceChannelLabel = Omni Setup Flow Cases
serviceChannelDevName = Omni_Setup_Flow_Cases
serviceChannelId = 0N95j000000CkiJCAS
Outputs:
None.`

Comment: I'm encountering a similar error in the chat routing process where we're directed to an agent, but an error appears in the route work "**ROUTE WORK: Route Work to Agent Inputs:** ". We haven't utilized the "check availability" decision in our flow, because we are receiving a standard message stating "agents not available" as soon as the chat initiates. If any solution is there to why above error appears within the flow in route work, please share it with us.